# Third Party Node Module Dependencies are not working in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, node-modules, angular-carousel

I tried to include the carousel in my angular project and added the required dependencies via `npm install angular-jk-carousel --save` and its gets installed in node_modules folder successfully,

Src
https://github.com/juank11memphis/angular-jk-carousel
and added `jkAngularCarousel` as dependency to module and included the script and css file in index and its not working,

**How to use the node module dependencies to include to work properly?**

```
myproject/
      --/bower-components/
      --/gulp/
      --/.tmp/
      --/node-modules/
            ---/angular-jk-carousel
      --/src/
            ---/app
               ----/app.module.js
               ----/app.run.js
               ----/app.route.js
               ----/mydev/
               -------/app.mydev.module.js
               -------/app.mydev.config.js
               -------/app.mydev.controller.js
               -------/app.mydev.tmpl.html 
            ---/index.html
      --package.json
      --bower.json
      --gulpfile.js
      --.bowerrc
```

app.module.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app', [
            'ui.router','ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'ngSanitize', 'ngMessages', 'ngMaterial','googlechart', 'chart.js', 'ui.calendar', 'angularMoment', 'uiGmapgoogle-maps', 'md.data.table', 'ngFileUpload','app.mydev',
'jkAngularCarousel'
        ])       
})();
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ABC",
  "version": "2.5.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-jk-carousel": "^0.1.6",
    //other dependencies
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <!-- build:css({.tmp/serve,src}) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css({.tmp/serve,src}) styles/app.css -->
    <!-- inject:css -->
    <!-- css files will be automatically insert here -->
    <!-- endinject -->
   <!-- endbuild -->
  </head>
  <body translate-cloak ng-class="bodyClasses">
    <div layout="row" ui-view="main"></div>

    <!-- build:js(src) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:js({.tmp/serve,.tmp/partials,src}) scripts/app.js -->
    <!-- inject:js -->
    <!-- js files will be automatically insert here -->
    <!-- endinject -->

    <!-- inject:partials -->
    <!-- angular templates will be automatically converted in js and inserted here -->
    <!-- endinject -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

      <script src="../node_modules/angular-jk-carousel/dist/jk-carousel.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../node_modules/angular-jk-carousel/dist/jk-carousel.min.css" >

  </body>
</html>
```

console

```
GET http://localhost:3001/node_modules/angular-jk-carousel/dist/jk-carousel.min.js 
(index):316 GET http://localhost:3001/node_modules/angular-jk-carousel/dist/jk-carousel.min.js 
angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module jkAngularCarousel due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'jkAngularCarousel' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Comment: Is the jk-carousel.min.js loaded from the node_modules folder or do you get an 404 error there?

Comment: It showing 404 error

Comment: okay, then move the jk-carousel files from node_modules folder to your app src folder (or any folder which is accessible from the frontend).